# Unable to verify details inside a modal using nightwatch js

Tags: javascript, selenium, e2e-testing

Application has a pincode link which opens a modal which accepts pincode. I am unable to enter pincode inside modal using nightwatch js. application link: hometown.in

I have tried

```
.waitForElementVisible('/html/body/div[7]/div/div/div/div/input', 3000)
```

but didnt worked.[screenshot of page HTML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9PUpC.png)

Comment: Could you paste your HTML into the question body instead of posting a screenshot? This issue will be a little easier to troubleshoot with that.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using a relative XPath, as they tend to be more robust.

```
.waitForElementVisible('input[placeholder='Enter Pincode / City']')
```

It looks like this code just waits for the element to exist. You need to send some text to this element as well:

```
 browser.setValue('input[placeholder='Enter Pincode / City']', ['3000', browser.Keys.ENTER]);
```

Comment: Not working.Getting error  as NoSuchElementError: An error occurred while running .setValue() command on <//input[@placeholder="Enter Pincode / City"]>:
screenshot link: https://ibb.co/ynLyMP5